# Could not save list changes to server (2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list

I use Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Created a new sharepoint website in sharepoint online, created a custom list within and wanted to create a new form. But sharepoint simply does not save the change. But it does not tell why.

> Could not save list changes to server

Do I need specific permissions? How to enable detailed debugging? Do you know why that occurs?

I already checked [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150299/could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server) answer, but for me there are no current data sets and no custom columns. It is a new list and a new sharepoint website.

Comment: check if you need this permission...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: There ought to be some error if you are not seeing the changes. IF you really need the community help. Please write down the steps you followed for creating a custom form. BE detailed as possible.

Comment: may i know how you are creating a new form for custom list?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Tom I don't know. It was a question more than a year ago. I am not sure if I have resolved it. I don't work with Sharepoint Designer anymore.

Comment: @Peter lucky you.